# why hyris introduced commercewebservices as we can use spring rest services?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

Why hybris introduced commerce webservices/occ, as we already have spring rest services. Also in commerce webservices also we will use Spring Rest Services only.

Please clarify me.

Answer (score 1):

occ extension has OOTB rest services. These services used by Spartacus store front now. Old commercewebservices extension has limited functionality. They can extend it but they didn't do that. Maybe they afraid broke existing rest services which are developed by customers.